# Why is my integer range not working?

Tags: xcode, int

Im working with Body Mass Index and im wonder why my "range" system is only setting a label to one value. Is there a better way to set this up that will work much better?

```
   int bmiInt = currentBMI;
if ( 0<=bmiInt <= 18.5) {
    weightStatus.text = @"Status: Underweight";
}
if (18.6 <= bmiInt <= 24.9) {
    weightStatus.text = @"Status: Normal weight";
}
if (25 <= bmiInt <= 29.9) {
    weightStatus.text = @"Status: Overweight";
}
if (bmiInt >= 30) {
    weightStatus.text = @"Status: Obese";
}
```

For some reason weightStatus.text is always equal to @"Status Overweight" even if bmiInt is not inside that range. Why?

Comment: never written xcode, but most languages don't allow chaining operators like that.. shouldn't it be `if ((0 <= bmiInt) && (bmiInt <= 18.5))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0 <= bmiInt <= 18.5` doesn't do what you think it does. The return value of a comparison operator is either `0` or `1`, denoting true and false. This expression can be rewritten as `(0 <= bmiInt) <= 18.5`, which means that after evaluating the first comparison `0 <= bmiInt`, you're going to end up with `0 <= 18.5` or `1 <= 18.5`, which both evaluate to `1`, which passes the conditional.

This is going to be true for your first 3 conditionals, which means that unless `bmiInt >= 30` evaluates to true, then your label is always going to show `@"Status: Overweight"`.

You want to rewrite this like

```
if (0 <= bmiInt && bmiInt <= 18.5) {
    ...
}
```